# Too Many database connections on Amazon RDS dropping connection

Tags: codeigniter, mysqli, amazon-ec2, database-connection, amazon-rds

I need to import a large user base in my application. But while stress and load testing I found that, after 200-300 concurrent requests, mysql starts rejecting the calls and gives the below error.

> Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in
>   codeigniter/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php on line
>   374.

I am using `AWS RDS(db.m1.small)` for database and `EC2 instance(m1.small)` as server and `CodeIgniter` framework.

Comment: You might want to ask your question at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Have posted the same question at serverfault.com.
http://serverfault.com/questions/764287/too-many-database-connections-on-amazon-rds-dropping-connection